# On my Gateway DX4840-37, can I add 2x 4GB RAM sticks on top of the existing 2x 2GB RAM?

Tags: memory, upgrade, gateway

On my Gateway DX4840-37 desktop, can I add 2x 4GB RAM on top of the existing 2x 2GB RAM?

Current memory: 2x Samsung 2GB DDR3 PC3-10600 1333MHz DIMM Non-ECC RAM on Blue slots.

I want to add: 2x 4GB Patriot DDR3 PC3-10600 1333MHz DIMM Non-ECC RAM.

Is it okay to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The HS57 chipset supports that configuration and two sources I checked with indicate no restrictions for the DX4840-37. So it should work. Leave the existing memory in the same slots when you install the new memory to preserve your dual-channel configuration.